# Returns a boolean value for whether any two distinct numbers in an array add up to an interger

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, arraylist

I'm practicing Python, I want to write a function which takes an array of integers x, and an integer y,and returns a boolean value for whether any two distinct numbers in x add up to y, for example:

```
add_check([1, 1, 2], 2) # Returns True
add_check([1, 1, 2], 3) # Returns True

add_check([2, 3], 4) # Returns False
```

Here is my incomplete solution:

```
def add_check(x: list, y: int):

    # create a dict object and add all the element in the list to the list 
    dictionary = {}
    for i in range(len(x)):
        dictionary.update({x[i]: i})
        #print(dictionary)

    for i in range(len(x)):
        second_num = y - x[i]
        if second_num in dictionary.values():
            second_index = x.index(second_num)
            if i != second_index:
                print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

But when I run `add_check([1, 1, 2], 2)` it returns `True False`.
I'm a bit confused now, can someone help please, many thanks.

Comment: print is not the same as return. Only return will stop the function and give its value to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `print` statement just shows an info, but the code continues and the `for/else` structure work like this

> The `else` statement will be executed if no`break` statement have been used in the loop

So you'd need to use a `break` after printing `True`

```
def add_check(x: list, y: int):
    dictionary = {}
    for i in range(len(x)):
        dictionary.update({x[i]: i})

    for i in range(len(x)):
        second_num = y - x[i]
        if second_num in dictionary.values():
            second_index = x.index(second_num)
            if i != second_index:
                print(True)
                break
    else:
        print(False)
```

---

#### Improvements and fixes

- you could use a `return` rather than a `print`, that's stop the code, and that's nicer to let the caller do the job rather than the method
- `dictionary.values()` contains indices, and not the values from `x` so it can be misleading, can a value can be an indice then not be found in `x` and raise an error like `add_check([2, 3], 4)` example

So you may check if the missing value for the sum is a key in the dictionnary, and if so, verofy that it's last position (stored in `dictionary`) isn't the current indice

```py
def add_check(x: list, y: int):
    dictionary = {value: i for i, value in enumerate(x)}
    for i, value in enumerate(x):
        second_index = dictionary.get(y - value)
        if second_index and i != second_index:
            return True
    return False

print(add_check([1, 1, 2], 2))  # True
print(add_check([1, 2, 2], 4))  # True
print(add_check([1, 1, 2], 3))  # True
print(add_check([2, 3], 4))     # False
```

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question, why we use `if second_index and i != second_index:` instead of `if i != second_index:`?

Answer (score 2):

Your code confuses values and indexes. For example in `[11, 3, 4, 7]`, the elements have indexes `0, 1, 2, 3` respectively but the values are `[11, 3, 4, 7]`.

Your goal is to add up the *values*. I suggest coding without indexes at all: use `for value in x` rather than `for i in range(len(x))` , both to avoid such confusing and for more Pythonic code.